# SQL Server 2008 : Row_Number() Always Ordering ASC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort the rows on the basis of input parameters but it always sorting in ASC order.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NAME
    @order VARCHAR(4),
    @col VARCHAR(100),
    @locationId int,
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                                   CASE WHEN @order = 'asc' AND @col = 'Time' 
                                           THEN [Time] 
                                   END ASC,
                                   CASE WHEN @order = 'desc' AND @col = 'Time' 
                                           THEN [Time] 
                                   END DESC) AS Row#,
        Col1, COl2, COl3,
    FROM 
        Table_ 
    WHERE 
        ID = @locationid
END

EXEC SP_NAME 'asc', 'Time' > Sorting in ASC
EXEC SP_NAME 'desc', 'Time' > Sortin in ASC
```

Please help me find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Works on my machine. Try to repro your issue in a sql fiddle.

Comment: @Will There is where clause also. Updated the question

Comment: Still doesn't help.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I would probably name my params to make sure the order is always correct, else this won't work.   `EXEC SP_NAME @order = 'asc', @col =  'Time'`

Comment: I am guessing the `@locationid` matters here, and you do not parse any value to it, doubt it will work

Comment: You're missing an `ORDER BY Row#`. Without that nothing is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guaranty that the ROW_NUMBER() statement will sort your result set, you should do something like:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                               CASE WHEN @order = 'asc' AND @col = 'Time' 
                                       THEN [Time] 
                               END ASC,
                               CASE WHEN @order = 'desc' AND @col = 'Time' 
                                       THEN [Time] 
                               END DESC) AS Row#,
    Col1, COl2, COl3,
FROM 
    Table_ 
WHERE 
    ID = @locationid
ORDER BY Row# ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    Row# = CASE WHEN @order = 'DESC' THEN 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                               CASE WHEN @col = 'Time' THEN 
                                        [Time] 
                               END DESC) 
            ELSE
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                               CASE WHEN @col = 'Time' THEN 
                                        [Time] 
                               END ASC) 
            END,
    Col1, COl2, COl3,
FROM 
    Table_ 
WHERE 
    ID = @locationid
```